# React | JavaScript : Unable to update an array using map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, rxjs

I am working on a restaurant app and need to update the the **orders** feature.
**LOGIC**
= If the item added by clicking **"+"** :

1. It needs to check if the order already exists (if yes, then
   increment the quantity)
2. If not then append that item to the
   orders list

CODE:

```
let orders = [];
    const addMore = (e) => {
        let sign = e.target.innerText;
        // if the item already exists in orders 
        const updatedOrder = orders.map(each => {
            if( each.id === e.target.id && sign === "+"){
                return {
                  ...each, qty: each.qty + 1   
                }
            } 
            else if (each.id === e.target.id && sign === "-"){
                return {
                    ...each, qty: each.qty - 1
                }
            } else return each;
        });
        console.log(updatedOrder);   // < ------ SHOWS EMPTY !!
        orders = updatedOrder;
        fullMenu.map(each => {
            if(each._id === e.target.id && sign === '+') {
                setTotal( total + parseInt(each.price) );
                orders.push({
                    id: each._id,
                    name: each.name,
                    price: each.price,
                    type: each.isVeg ? "veg" : "non-veg",
                    qty: 1
                });    
            }
        });
    }
```

**Issue** : It's not running the updatedOrder loop. It shows empty.

DATA SCHEMA:

```
{
   _id: 5eef61450bd95e1f5c8f372f
   name: "Burger"
   category: "American"
   price: "100"
   isVeg: false
   __v: 0
}
```

Comment: `orders` is an empty array, there is nothing to map.

Comment: It would get filled in the code below

Comment: Are you expecting `fullMenu.map` to run before `updatedOrder = orders.map`? The code you have posted is not going to do that. If there is some other function or state effect in your component that populates `orders` before `updateOrder = orders.map` then you need to post it too.

Comment: Usually the first thing you do is have a look at the redux dev tools note what actions are dispatched and what state changes they produce and then ask a question with the relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should store `orders` also in a state

**Example**

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([{
     id: "5eef61450bd95e1f5c8f372f",
     name: "Burger",
     category: "American",
     price: "100",
     isVeg: false,
     __v: 0
  }])
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([])
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0)

  const addMore = ({target: {id, innerText: sign}}) => {
        
    const newOrders = [...orders];
    let order = newOrders.find(pr => pr.id === id);
        
    if(order) {
      let _sign = sign === "+" ? 1 : -1;
      
      order.qty = (order.qty || 0) + 1 * _sign
      
      if(!order.qty) {
        setOrders(orders => orders.filter(pr => pr.id !== id));
        setTotal(total => total - parseInt(order.price));
        return;
      }
      
      setOrders(newOrders);
      setTotal(total => total + _sign * parseInt(order.price));
      return;
      
    }
        
    const product = products.find(pr => pr.id === id);
    order = {
      ...product,
      qty: 1
    }
    setOrders(orders => [...orders, order]);
    setTotal(total => total + parseInt(order.price));
  }

  return <div>
    {products.map(({id, name, category, price}) => <div className="product" key={id}>
      <div>{name} {category} {price}$</div>
      <button id={id} onClick={addMore}>+</button>
      <button id={id} onClick={addMore}>-</button>
    </div>)}
    <div>Total: {total}</div>
    <div>{JSON.stringify(orders, null, 4)}</div>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```css
.product {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: That is so cool how you did it. Thanks. Can you please explain me how you destructured : ({target: {id, innerText: sign}})  ??

Comment: [mdn has quite good overview of object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Nested_object_and_array_destructuring)

Comment: Hi, I used your logic, can you review it? It's giving me errors. Posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
const addMore = (e) => {
        let sign = e.target.innerText;
        let id = e.target.id;
        const newOrders = [...orders];
        let order = newOrders.find(each => each.id === id);
        // if the order already exists for the item
        if (order) {
            let _sign = sign === "+" ? 1 : -1;
            // increase or decrease the quantity
            order.qty = (order.qty || 0) + 1 * _sign;
            // remove item from order list if qty = 0
            if(!order.qty){
                setOrders(orders => orders.filter(pr => pr.id !== id));
                // setTotal(total => total - parseInt(order.price));
                return;
            };
            // save 
            setOrders(newOrders);
            if (sign === "+") setTotal(total => total + parseInt(order.price));
            if (sign === "-") setTotal(total => total - parseInt(order.price));
            return;
        };
        // if item doesn't exist in the order list
        const item = fullMenu.find(each => each._id === id);
        if (sign === "+") {
            order = {
                ...item, qty: 1 
             };
            setOrders(orders => [...orders, order]);
            setTotal(total => total + parseInt(order.price));
        };
    }
```